# Connecting to MongoDB via mongoose gives auth fail error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect to my Mongo cluster using a connection string like this:

```
module.exports = {
  MongoURI: MongoURI: 'mongodb+srv://philip:DummyPassword9$@test-cluster-026fd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
}
```

And have set my configuration in the app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').MongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected....'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

//EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

But instead of connecting to the Mongo cluster I get an error:

```
MongoError: authentication fail
```

I read everything that I could find online related to this problem, I tried encoding my password like this:

```
module.exports = {
  MongoURI: `mongodb+srv://philip:${encodeURIComponent('DummyPassword9')}$@test-cluster-026fd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`
}
```

But still I can't connect and I get this error. I am sure that my account password is right, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting via a url, so you have to change your password to URL encoding format.
Replace **"$"** with **"%24"** and check.
Reference : [HTML URL ENCODINGS](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)